# How to assign json kafka message to Java object?

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I created a kafka consumer service using spring boot. I need to get the message from the kafka and assign it to the java object and do some calculations according to the data in the object and store it in MongoDB database.

Here is my kafka listner.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "neworder", groupId = "group_json",
        containerFactory = "orderKafkaListenerFactory")
public void consumeJson(List<Order> order) {
   System.out.println("Consumed JSON Message: " + order);
}
```

Here is the received kafka message.

> Consumed JSON Message: [{Id=11, FualType=Petrol 92, Capacity=33000}]

Here is my Java class.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

 @Document("Order")
 public class Order {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String type;
    private int capacity;

public Order() {
}

public Order(int id, String type, int capacity) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
```

}

I need to assign the received message data from kafka to this java class.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why write Java code to write to Mongo? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.7/sink-connector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are getting some errors at the moment. It would help if you could add them to your question.

First, since the fields in the json of the Kafka message do not match those of your java class, you have to annotate them:

```
@Id
@JsonProperty("Id")
private int id;

@JsonProperty("FualType")
private String type;

@JsonProperty("Capacity")
private int capacity;
```

In terms of configuration of the consumer, normally it is enough to configure the JsonDeserializer for the value of the kafka message and use it in the ConsumerFactory:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, List<Order>> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
    ...
    return props;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. your answer solved the error in my code. However, still, It does not assign values to my Java class.  My final goal is to store those values in MongoDB. Since still kafka message data does not assign to the java class. I am unable to store them in the database.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it helped you move forward with the issue. Are there any errors in the log still? Also, how do you do the saving to mongo in the 'consumeJson' method?

Comment: There are no errors in the log, I thought to create a repository interface and extend it by MongoRepository and use the save method in the MongoRepository interface. It requires the object of my java class